# Not able to copy data from one List to another using Collections.copy() method

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am trying to copy one List data into another using Collections.copy method but it is giving me IndexOutofBoundsException exception.

**Source Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> odds = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 7, 9);
    System.out.println("odds = " + odds);

    //copy data from one to another using copy() method
    List<Integer> anotherOdd = new ArrayList<>(odds.size());
    Collections.copy(anotherOdd, odds);
    System.out.println("anotherOdd = " + anotherOdd);
}

odds = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Source does not fit in dest
    at java.util.Collections.copy(Unknown Source)
    at com.study.java.collections.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Collections.copy` is only intended to be used when you have two lists of the same size already.  Note this sentence from the `Collections.copy` Javadoc:

> The destination list must be at least as long as the source list.

Your `anotherOdd` list has *capacity* `odds.size()` but *size* 0.  The line `new ArrayList<>(odds.size())` just gives an estimate for how long the `ArrayList` is going to be, it doesn't actually mean the list has that size.

But the solution is simple: just use `anotherOdd.addAll(odds)`, or even better, just write `List<Integer> anotherOdd = new ArrayList<>(odds)`.

Comment: Per the doc excerpt, "the same size" isn't quite the right characterization.

Answer (score 1):

The `ArrayList` constructor your using here `List<Integer> anotherOdd = new ArrayList<>(odds.size());` is to specify capacity not the size